# React datepicker cutting calendar on mobile screen

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using **react-datepicker**.

I have two **datepicker** in the one line, and it is working perfect on desktop screen but when using it on mobile screen, calendar is cutting from right side as it did not got enough space from right side.

Further, It is also **not showing scrollbar to scroll to right side**.

Below is the image how it looks on mobile.

[image: image_on_mobile]

Comment: You might consider adding a bit of CSS to wrap the "To:" label and button to the next line. Then you don't need to deal with the awkward UX scrollbars will introduce.

Comment: @AndyHoffman, I don't want to show 'To' Button to the next line.

Comment: Can I suggest you to try react-numpad

Comment: @Pietro, what is this? Yes, you can suggest.

Comment: it's another react component with calendar functionalities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing a little research into the repository, it appears this is a [known issue](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/1045). One suggestion is to use the [portal version](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-28) of the date picker, which puts the date picker in a modal. You could preserve the current behavior for larger screens and use the portal solution for mobile only.

[image]

Comment: @AndyThanks, I will test it.

Comment: Does not work well if you have `showTimeSelect` prop.

Answer (score 16):

I just came across this issue

On *smaller* viewports, the calendar is cutoff by the window. (overflows off screen to right or the left)

In order to solve this issue, I had to use the `popperModifiers` prop

More specifically, `popperModifiers.preventOverflow`

```
<DatePicker
  ...
  popperModifiers={{
    preventOverflow: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  }}
</DatePicker>
```

Checkout the popperModifiers [Docs Here](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/master/docs/popper_component.md)

Comment: Does this cause problems somewhere else? Otherwise, why is this not the default?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by using the following code:

```
.react-datepicker{
    position:absolute !important;
    right: -290px !important;
}
```

This fixes the problem for all screen sizes

You won't see the `.react-datepicker` class in your css. This is built into the npm package.

You will have to play with the `right: -290px` figure to get the right figure that works for your code.

[image]